# How to cancel large file download yet still get page source in C#?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I'm working in C# on a program to list all course resources for a MOOC (e.g. Coursera). I don't want to download the content, just get a listing of all the resources (e.g. pdf, videos, text files, sample files, etc...) which are made available to the course.

My problem lies in parsing the html source (currently using HtmlAgilityPack) without downloading all the content.

For example, if you go to this [intro video for a banking course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/money) and check the source (F12 in Chrome for Developer Tools), you can see the page source. I can stop the video download which autoplays, but still see the source.

How can I get the source in C# without download all the content?
I've looked in the HttpWebRequest headers (problem: time out), and DownloadDataAsync with Cancel (problem: the Completed Result object is invalid when cancelling the async request). I've also tried various Loads from HtmlAgilityPack but with no success.

Time out:

```
        HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        postRequest.Timeout = TIMEOUT * 1000000; //Really long
        postRequest.Referer = "https://www.coursera.org"; 

        if (headers != null)
        { //headers here }

        //Deal with cookies
        if (cookie != null)
        { cookieJar.Add(cookie); }

        postRequest.CookieContainer = cookiejar;
        postRequest.Method = "GET";
        postRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = allowRedirect;
        postRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
        HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)postRequest.GetResponse();
```

Any tips on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do what you're asking. The first is to use a range get. That is, specify the range of the file you want to read. You do that by calling [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ds43y3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `HttpWebRequest`. So if you want, say, the first 10 kilobytes of the file, you'd write:

```
request.AddRange(-10240);
```

Read carefully what the documentation says about the meaning of that parameter. If it's negative, it specifies the *ending* point of the range. There are also other overloads of `AddRange` that you might be interested in.

Not all servers support range gets, though. If that doesn't work, you'll have to do it another way.

What you can do is call `GetResponse` and then start reading data. Once you've read as much data as you want, you can stop reading and close the stream. I've modified your sample slightly to show what I mean.

```
string url = "https://www.coursera.org/course/money";
HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
postRequest.Method = "GET";
postRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true; //allowRedirect;
postRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse) postRequest.GetResponse();
int maxBytes = 1024*1024;
int totalBytesRead = 0;
var buffer = new byte[maxBytes];
using (var s = postResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    int bytesRead;
    // read up to `maxBytes` bytes from the response
    while (totalBytesRead < maxBytes && (bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, maxBytes)) != 0)
    {
        // Here you can save the bytes read to a persistent buffer,
        // or write them to a file.
        Console.WriteLine("{0:N0} bytes read", bytesRead);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("total bytes read = {0:N0}", totalBytesRead);
```

That said, I ran this sample and it downloaded about 6 kilobytes and stopped. I don't know why you're having trouble with timeouts or too much data.

Note that sometimes trying to close the stream before the entire response is read will cause the program to hang. I'm not sure why that happens at all, and I can't explain why it only happens sometimes. But you can solve it by calling `request.Abort` before closing the stream. That is:

```
using (var s = postResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    // do stuff here
    // abort the request before continuing
    postRequest.Abort();
}
```

Comment: GetResponseStream() was the way to do it. My final implementation first read the headers (GetResponseHeader("name-of-header")) to get the file name of the autoplaying video, then cast the response stream to a StreamReader.