# Prevent WebBrowser from downloading PDF

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to download some PDF's using a WebBrowser. [This URL](http://www.globalspec.com/pdf/viewpdf?comp=3576&vid=99490&partId=%7B4D64B6F4-E19B-41E5-8215-0F7A38897A3D%7D&from=mi) contains an `iframe` with the `src` attribute set to [this other URL](http://www.globalspec.com/GoTo/GoToWebPage?Context=Part:1200V,%20NPT%20IGBT%20--%20HGTP10N120BN&gotoURL=https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/HG/HGTP10N120BN.pdf&gototype=TocPartWebPage&VID=99490&Comp=3576&OemId=0), which in turn has a 302 redirect to [this URL](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/HG/HGTP10N120BN.pdf), which is a PDF file.

When I visit the first URL with a WebBrowser, it downloads and opens the file using Acrobat Reader. I would like to prevent this from happening because I'd like to automate the WebBrowser to visit many of these pages programmatically and don't want a bunch of Adobe Acrobat launching all over.

I have access to the `DWebBrowserEvents2` and all of its events. One of the events getting fired was `NavigateError`, with the URL parameter pointing to the PDF file. I tried setting `cancel` to `true`, but the file was still being downloaded.

Is there any other way I can programmatically cancel the download?

Comment: take a look here and see if the accepted answer helps looks like you can accomplish the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443572/how-to-cancel-large-file-download-yet-still-get-page-source-in-c

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to be able to do this with a WebBrowser control since I already have an application built around it.

Comment: well based on the link within the webbrowser control .. I am sure that you could get something like that to work.. but then again I don't know what your code looks like so I am in the dark like the rest of us..

Comment: @MethodMan I just need to be able to visit the first URL using a WebBrowser without launching Acrobat Reader. I don't have any code related to this because I don't even know where to start. I believe I'll have to access some of the obscure native interfaces and am hoping someone knows which one will allow me to accomplish this. If you still think my code would help you help me let me know which section you think would help. Right now I have like a thousand lines of code wrapper around a WebBrowser.

Comment: [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) and [this link (c++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753618%28VS.85%29.aspx) may give you some help.

Comment: @Sakura so close. I think the Navigated event is what OP wanted, since from there you can access the response. Navigating happens before the click. But otherwise, this OP, use this.

Comment: @SimonHalsey What should I do in the Navigated event? There's no Cancel property in the argument.

Comment: You could save the response to disk which is the file you asked for & prevent it from appearing in the browser. I'd experiment to see what you can do with this event.